# Pass Jenkins Enviromental variable values jenkins job's builds parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have installed **build parameterized plugin** in Jenkins. I want to pass Jenkins Environmental Variable **(env.WORKSPACE)** to a pipeline job as a string parameter. But, it Could not take the workspace value. Instead, it prints as **(env.WORKSPACE)** as I have passed to a pipeline job. Please provide a better suggestion to achieve that
[Jenkins jobs Configuration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reXJk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can access them by using

```
params.WORKSPACE
```

in your Groovy Script.

Or you define your job in another way as described in

https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines

Comment: I have set the enviromental in configure System.I want to get that enviromental variable in jenkins job build parameter plugin's default value.It's not needed in grrovy script